# Webcam DELL WB5023 not working on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: webcam

I can't make the new DELL Webcam WB5023 working on Ubuntu 22.04.

When I plus the webcam, dmesg show me this:

```
usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
usb 1-2: config 1 has an invalid interface number: 5 but max is 2
usb 1-2: config 1 has no interface number 2
usb 1-2: config 1 interface 5 altsetting 0 endpoint 0x84 has an invalid bInterval 0, changing to 7
usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=413c, idProduct=c022, bcdDevice= 0.26
usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
usb 1-2: Product: Dell Webcam WB5023
usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Alpha Imaging Tech. Corp.
usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 892E40DCF673
usb 1-2: Found UVC 1.00 device Dell Webcam WB5023 (413c:c022)
uvcvideo 1-2:1.1: Failed to set UVC probe control : -32 (exp. 26).
input: Dell Webcam WB5023 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/input/input33
hid-generic 0003:413C:C022.0008: hiddev1,hidraw4: USB HID v1.01 Device [Alpha Imaging Tech. Corp. Dell Webcam WB5023] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input5
usb 1-5.7: reset high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
```

It appears as a Webcam source on some app but don't work, Any idea to make it work ?

Thks